# What is considered a large database for an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

I'm just wondering what would be considered a large application (database portion) for the iphone?

Currently my database (sqlite) for my app is at 250mb and zipped at 27mb.

Both sizes to me seem unreasonably high for an app but i'm not that familiar with the app scene itself to know if that is considered too large.

Hope i can get some info from you guys on this and maybe even alternative methods i should consider.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20 MB app bundle size is the limit for 3G downloads. Over 20 MB, you cannot download the app except via WiFi or via a computer with iTunes. So you probably want to keep your app under the limit.

Comment: do you think a better approach would be to move the larger portions of the DB off the install and if the user wishes can download that data after installing the app adhoc like?

Comment: Something like this, yes. I've employed this approach myself. There's a core set of data (~4MB), and 60 MB extra that's either loaded from the 'Net upon request, or downloaded in entirety and cached in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

For sure it'd be good to pair down your DB, although how large your app should be depends greatly on the type of app.  For utility applications, the normal size is only a couple MB, but I'm not sure if that's what your app type is.